# Looking for a library similar to AForge.NET

Tags: video, camera

Is there something similar to AForge.NET but is able to be used with a C++ Visual Studio Project? I am using this framework to interface with DirectShow devices. I like how AForge.NET made it easy to interact with DirectShow devices. Looking for something like that. Particular functionality is displaying video from Camera.

Answer (score 0):

The LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK contains a [Capture Control](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/capture) that comes with C++ documentation, demos and code samples. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of this toolkit’s vendor).

You can find the Capture control’s C++ documentation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/api/leadtoolsmultimediafeatures-multimediafunctionreferences-iltmmcaptureinterface--rollup.html).
The control enumerates the DirectShow video sources, and you can access them through the [VideoDevices COM property](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/api/iltmmcapture-get-videodevices.html).

There are also features for previewing video on screen and capturing to video files in different formats.

You can try the control using the free evaluation of LEADTOOLS Multimedia from [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm). There’s also free technical support through email and chat during the evaluation.